# Extend Element prototype using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, prototype

Given the javascript like below, is there a corresponding TypeScript to do the same thing?

I just need to extend the html dom element prototype but cannot figure out a correct TypeScript to do this without compile errors.

```
Element.prototype.astyle = function actualStyle(props) {
    var el = this;
    var compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var style = compStyle[props[i]];
        if (style != null) {
            return style;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interface to extend the Element first.

```
interface Element{
    astyle(props:string[]);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to put this in a `.d.ts` file located in the same folder as your `tsconfig.json`